# Plane Wave Expansion method

Tags: mechanical-engineering, dynamics

I have very recently ventured into the domain of periodic structures. In the literature, I came across the Plane Wave Expansion method to compute the dispersion curves. I managed to code it in 1D . Can anyone please suggest some material (book/papers/anything) to extend the method in two dimensions. I tried to construct it based on 1D, but so far no success.